# Most elegant proof for: $xy>ab$ does not imply $x+y>a+b$?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples

Let $x,y,a,b$ be some constant real numbers.

**Q1:** Prove that $xy > ab$ does not imply that $x+y > a+b$ in the most elegant way?

**Q2:** What criteria do mathematicians use to define *elegance*?

### My attempt:

Suppose it does imply that. Let:

- $x=2$
- $y=2$
- $a=4$
- $b=0.5$

Then while the 1st inequality is true:
$$\begin{split}
xy&>ab\\
2\times 2&>4\times 0.5\\
3&>2\\
\end{split}$$
the second is false:
$$\begin{split}
x+y&>a+b\\
2+ 2&>4+ 0.5\\
4&>4.5\\
\end{split}$$

And that's hopefully a proof by contradiction.. or is it? I suspect that it's nasty and that I am doing some jumps somethere.

I would really appreciate guidance to reach a proof for this simple problem that is most rigor and most elegant.

Comment: This is totally rigorous. It is enough to show that the statement is false for some case, at least for the field $\Bbb R$ is enough because you are using real numbers here.

Comment: It's an interesting question in and of itself, but asking this on an exam or as a homework exercise is frankly absurd. Mathematics is not subjective. "Elegance" is.

Comment: You find a counterexample, that's it. Nothing too elegant about that.

Comment: But here I had to think to pick special numbers that would show the contradiction. Is there a way to prove that without having to have me pick special numbers? I.e. proving it purely by symbols? Wouldn't it be more elegant this way?

Comment: A single counterexample suffices but we could search for some really 'clean' or enlightening ones. eg take $a=0$ $b $ huge, $x$ and $y $ both $1$.

Comment: $a=b=1$, $x=y=-2$ is even easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single counterexample suffices. Put
$$x=y=3\ ,\qquad a=8,\quad b=1\ .$$
Then $xy>ab$, but $x+y<a+b$.

Comment: Could you please also write the full wordings around this proof?

Comment: @caveman I already see "the full wordings around the proof" in this answer.

Comment: @Did, don't mathematicians when writing perfectly rigor proofs also need to state the method of the proof? E.g. proof by contradiction, deduction, induction, etc?

Comment: No. And the OP did exactly that in the first sentence of their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = (a, b)$ and $X = (x, y)$ be points in the first (positive $X, Y$) quadrant of the $X-Y$ plane with $x, y \ne 0$. Let $R_A$ and $R_X$ be the rectangles formed by parallels to the axes to these points (e.g. $R_A $ has vertices $(0, 0), (0, b), (a, b), (a, 0))$.

For any finite values $w, z$ we can choose $A $ with length greater than $w$ and area $R_A < z$ by moving the point $A$ far along one axis and close to the other.

Therefore we can choose a point $A$ with $a > x + y$ and $ab < xy$, and since $b $ is also positive then $a + b > x + y$ and $ ab < xy$.

(i.e. $xy > ab$ and $x + y \not \gt a + b$ )

P.S. - I think that is elegant.

Comment: I have problems understanding your wordings and I'd appreciate clarifications. You say * let $A=(a,b)$ and $X=(x,y)$ be points*. Are they really points? To me these are just two single points. Do you mean that $\mathcal{A} = \{(a,b):a\in\mathbb{R}, b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a set? (and a similar for $\mathcal{X}$).  Or maybe just $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{X}=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ where $\times$ is the Cartesian product? Also when you say that $X-Y$ is a plane, what is $Y$?